# Git - ignore file on merge but still push it to remote

Tags: git, merge, sass, gitignore

I am working on a project with a lot of sass files that get compiled into one big `style.css`

The problem is that this `style.css` is always causing problems when merging, but we still want its latest version pushed to the server. What I end up doing - is remove my local `style.css` file when merging with master, then compile sass again and only then push everything to remote.

How would I ignore a particular file when merging but still push it to remote when I'm pushing the master branch?

EDIT:
Basically I always want my version of this file override the one on master branch without causing conflicts and the rest of the files be merged as usual.

Comment: you merge it with master, but you push it to master. ??

Comment: I think YemSalat wanted to say "when pulling".

Comment: Can't you generate the style.css on the server via the sass files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: you may want to do this:

```
[(*) code and commit]
[don't commit your style.css!]
$ git checkout -- public/style.css                # erase your own style.css
$ git pull
[merge if necessary]
[re-generate your style.css]                      # important!
git commit public/style.css -m "your message here"
git push origin                                   # should be OK.
[go to (*) and go on coding]
```

---

### Original post

I think there are several ways to achieve this.

1. `style.css` might not be tracked by git as it will be generated again.
2. If ever you are using a static site generator, you should push your `public/` directory with rsync instead of git. In that case, you will not have to keep track of this `style.css`.
3. Separate commits for style.css and Before merging, use `git cherry pick` to merge and override specific files.
4. Do you need `style.css` to exist in master? If not, maintain a separate branch for your `style.css`, ignore the CSS in `master` and the `style.css`'s branch will contain a specific `.gitignore` in your public directory containing `!style.css`. As a consequence this specific branch will have only 2 files, and you automatically merge master inside.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know we can't forcefully push single file

For now what you can do is
1)After runing sass save style.css separately and checkout to current version(only style.css) and push the code.

2) now copy saved style.css and then commit, use git force command to force push it to remote.

```
git push -f <remote> <branch>
```

(or)

use git ignore style.css, once ignored it will not be tracked but you will end up with copying latest style.css to server every time

Comment: I guess the problem occurs in _pulling_ instead of pushing (as it is a merge issue). Isn't that right?